# What port(s) can I use for a messenger application

Tags: c, tcp, port, ports

Please forgive me for being naive on the subject, however, I do not understand ports and how they work in the slightest. I am trying to make a program where two computers could communicate given their IP addresses and I am using TCP protocol. I don't, however, know what port(s) I would be able to use for this application, because when I look up TCP ports I get a list of ports each with their own function. Any help is useful.
P.S. I am using C to create my program

Comment: Just about anyone between 1024 and 65535 are okay to use for your own purpose.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is you can choose any port you like - although the safe range is generally considered to be between 1024 and 65535.  The only problem that you will encounter is when some other program installed on the device is already listening on that port. Unfortunately, there is no port that is guaranteed to be available to listen on.

One possible solution to this is to have a primary listening port and a fallback secondary port.  You can then first try to connect on the primary port and, if a satisfactory response is not received, try to connect on the secondary port.  However, even this is not infallible, as there is a chance that the secondary post could also be in use.

The easiest approach is to try to create your listener on the port that you have chosen, and if the port fails to create, let the user know that some other application is preventing execution of your application.